# Can I throw a weapon and then shoot a bow in a single full attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If I have a light hammer in one hand and a bow in the other, can I throw the hammer and then fire the bow as part of a full attack action?

Comment: I was half expecting the title to be a typo and the question to be "can I throw a bow?" This seems like an interesting attack routine, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

Pathfinder itself poses no limits as to the amount of different weapons you can use for your [full attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Attack) (all references to weapons in that text refer to Two-Weapon Fighting or double weapons), as long as you have enough attacks, and your action economy allows for switching weapons.

In your case, switching weapons is as simple as re-grabbing the bow with the second hand (rules speaking), which [according to the FAQ is a free action](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qda):

> **Two-Handed Weapons: What kind of action is it to remove your hand from a two-handed weapon or re-grab it with both hands?**
>
> Both are free actions. For example, a wizard wielding a quarterstaff can let go of the weapon with one hand as a free action, cast a spell as a standard action, and grasp the weapon again with that hand as a free action; this means the wizard is still able to make attacks of opportunity with the weapon (which requires using two hands).
>
> As with any free action, the GM may decide a reasonable limit to how many times per round you can release and re-grasp the weapon (one release and re-grasp per round is fair).

So unless you get into really strange shenanigans which cause your GM to restrict the usage of free actions (like making multiple shield bashes with a [quickdraw shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor/quickdraw-shield) in between greatsword swings), your action economy is not affected by it.

Do note that the hammer throw will use your highest attack bonus since it's the first attack in your full attack.

Comment: Actually, you hold a bow with your off-hand anyway - you hold the arrow in your primary hand. So it'd be "throw hammer (as an attack), draw arrow (as *a standard part of* an attack)".

Comment: Technically, multiple shield bash shenanigans between greatsword swings would require Quickdraw + Quickdraw Shield (as this makes it a free action, rather than a swift one).